# Send Email using If Statements and lookups

Tags: excel, vba, email

I am trying to send an email to a list of recipients when their list is triggered. I have lists of about 10 names in columns A:K of a sheet named "Email List".

I have another sheet called "Info Table". This sheet contains a table that includes a column where countries are located.

I am looking to add code that will do the following: When a country in the "Info Table" (Column C) matches a country in the "Email List" (row 2, columns A:K), an email will be sent to the email addresses listed in rows 3-13 for that country. The email at this stage can be generic.

```
Sub Send_Email()

    Dim Email_Subject, Email_Send_From, Email_Body As String, i As Integer
    Dim Mail_Object, nameList As String, o As Variant

    Email_Send_From = ""
    For i = 3 To 13 'use cells 3 to 13 in column "A" where names are stored

        If Sheets("Email List").Range("A3").Value <> "" Then
            nameList = nameList & ";" & Sheets("Email List").Range("A" & i).Value
        End If

    Next
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        .Subject = ""
        .To = nameList
        .Cc = ""
        .Body = "I am testing a new VBA, sorry if you received this message in error." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Best Regards," & vbNewLine & _
                ""
        .display
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `Application.VLookup` function which takes the same sort of arguments as the worksheet function of same name.

```
Dim myValue as Variant

'Modify the function to use YOUR arguments
myValue = Application.Vlookup(value_to_lookup, range_to_search, column_number, exact_match)

if IsError(myValue) Then 
    MsgBox "Not found!", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Please clarify what this means and it should be easy to help revise your code:

> When a country in the "Info Table" (Column C) matches a country in the
>   "Email List" (row 2, columns A:K), an email will be sent to the emails
>   listed in rows 3-13 for that country.

Specifically: what is going to trigger the `Send_Email` procedure? How will you call it? Does it need to be in a loop searching against *all* values in Info Table (column C)? Etc.

---

In the meantime, let's improve your code a bit. VBA does **not** support implicit type declarations, each variable must be `Dim` with it's own `As {type}`, otherwise it will be treated as `Variant`.  Best practice is to avoid variant in favor of strongly-typed variables whenever possible.

You can also avoid the `For i = 3 to 13` loop and assign to `nameList` in a single statement.

Then, I would just call this procedure in a loop over Column C, using the `Match` function to check if the country exists on the Email List worksheet.

```
Sub foo()
Dim c as Range
Dim match as Integer

With Sheets("Info Table")
    For each c in .Range("C1:C10").Cells ''Modify this as needed
        match = 0
        On Error Resume Next
        match = IfError( _
                     Application.Match( _
                         c.Value, Sheets("Email List").Range("A2:K2"), False)
                       )
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not match = 0 Then Call Send_Email(match)
    Next

End Sub
```

If it exists, then you send the result of the match function to the `Send_Email` procedure, and define the range using `match` to indicate the *column* which contains the email list for that particular country:

```
Sub Send_Email(match as Integer)

Dim Email_Subject As String, Email_Send_From  As String, Email_Body As String, i As Integer
Dim Mail_Object as Object, nameList As String, o As Variant

    Email_Send_From = ""

    If Sheets("Email List").Cells(match, 3).Value <> "" Then
        nameList = Join(Application.Transpose(Sheets("Email List").Range("A3:A13").Offset(,match-1).Value, ";")
    End If

    Next
    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        .Subject = ""
        .To = nameList
        .Cc = ""
        .Body = "I am testing a new VBA, sorry if you received this message in error." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                "Best Regards," & vbNewLine & _
                ""
        .display
    End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: You asked of it was possible to do a vlookup and the answer is yes. so, I'm a little confused about what your actual problem is... consider revising your question to provide more detail (and example data or screenshots).

Comment: Thank you for the clean up. The code is triggered through the use of a button. The workbook has a macro to gather data and create an exhaustive table. I then will trigger the email code to send emails to each list of people with the data relevant to them (based on country). In all, there will be about 15 countries of importance, the table is not typically that large, and on a weelky basis will only have 1 - 3 countries of interest. I update the table weekly.

Comment: I guess my question is how do you want it to *know* which country is of interest? This could easily be done with an `InputBox` control where you can indicate the column number (or letter), or the country name, etc...

Comment: But without knowing what you're actually trying to accomplish, it is difficult to suggest a course of action for you to follow.

Comment: The countries of interest are listed in their own columns in the 'Email list' sheet. On the 'Email List' sheet they are in Columns A2 - K2. The emails for each country are then listed in rows 3-13.

Comment: You've already said that.  how do you want it to know which country to send the email to?

Comment: each country that has a match.

Comment: ex. I have USA, Brazil, Japan...Table has USA, China, Japan, Columbia... Email is sent to USA with USA data and Japan with Japan data. I have the code for sending parts of a table. Just need help in the email part of this country match, receipients in this list...

Comment: ok so I think you want to call this in a loop. See revisions above maybe that will help.